# Dendrogram doesn't display proper leave names

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am trying to achieve such dendrogram by hierarchical clustering of eurostat data

[goal dendrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdzvS.png)

so far I was able to achieve such one
[current one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJkjQ.png)

Where did I lose the country names? Without using the *cut* function labels seem to be fine but the overall graph is cluttered.

I also have a question regarding the methodology. I was supposed to calculate the distance matrics according to Lp metrics where p=1.5, did I use the correct method for that? My plot looks different in terms of scale and overall leaves distribution.

```
library("eurostat")
library("countrycode")
data(efta_countries)
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")


d <- data.frame(label_eurostat(get_eurostat("prc_hicp_manr"))) %>%
  filter(time %in% as.Date("2020-01-01"):as.Date("2022-10-31"), 
         coicop == "All-items HICP", 
         geo %in% c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Chechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary",
                    "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", 
                    "Spain", "Sweden")) 

d2 <- data.frame(d[,c(3,5)])

#I was lacking aggregation, my only concern now is choosing the method
d2_grouped <- aggregate(values ~ geo, data = d2, mean)
d2_grouped

d3 <- scale(d2_grouped$values)
rownames(d3) <- d2_grouped$geo

d3_hclust  <- hclust(dist((d3), method = "minkowski", p = 1.5), method = "ward.D")
d3_dend <- as.dendrogram(d3_hclust)
plot(d3_dend)
```

Comment: Your data is not properly organized. You have 850 observations so you are trying to construct a dendrogram with 850 leaves. It looks like there are 25 different countries and you measuring the rate of change at 34 different dates. Perhaps you want to organize your data with 25 rows (countries) by 35 columns (1 unit and 34 dates)?

Comment: @dcarlson actually, could you help me with the aggregation - how do I also organize it by dates in columns. I tried:
d2_grouped <- aggregate(cbind(values, time) ~ geo, data = d2, mean)
but it doesn't work

Comment: When I run your updated code with `aggregate`, I get an appropriate-looking dendrogram - is there still a part of your question that hasn't been answered?

Comment: Your code seems to be working just fine. Your dendrogram groups countries by their average annual rate of change over the period 2020-01-01 to 2022-10-01. If you wanted to group countries by their growth rate fluctuations over time, you would want to create the layout I mentioned in my earlier comment. This would involve using `pivot_wider to create a column for each value in `time`.

Comment: oh okay, I wasn't sure because it doesn't look exactly like in the example (and it is supposed to) but I'm not allowed to use any additional packages so I can't use pivot_wider so I guess that's it.  It must be something regarding the method then but I can't figure out which to use